# PlotLegends only labels one of a list of functions

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a code in which I read data from a file and perform a number of fits. I wish to plot these fits on a single plot and add a legend which labels each line with a value which is saved in a list (of the same length as the number of fits). However, `PlotLegends` is only labelling one of the lines. As a simple example, if I run

```
leg = {1, 2};
Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> leg]
```

it produces

[image]

The legends are applied correctly. However, if I define the list of functions beforehand, it doesn't work. If I now run

```
fs = {x, x^2};
Plot[fs, {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> leg]
```

I get

[image]

There is no issue if I do a `ListPlot` however:

```
lfs = Table[Table[{x, x^j}, {x, 0, 2, 0.1}], {j, 1, 2}];
ListPlot[lfs, PlotLegends -> leg]
```

[image]

I suspect I am failing to understand how *Mathematica* interprets symbols such as `x` when defined the way I have defined here. For the purpose of my application, I am starting with discrete data points such as defined in `lfs` above, fitting curves, and then plotting:

```
fits = {Fit[lfs[[1]], {1, x}, x], Fit[lfs[[2]], {1, x, x^2}, x]};
Plot[fits, {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> leg]
```

[image]

But again I have the same issue as before.

Comment: It works correctly in 11.3. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I cannot reproduce the problem the user is experiencing; I suspect it is being caused by corrupted lexical elements in the OP's Mathematica notebook.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? This is a problem I consistently have across all of my notebooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Plot[fs, {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> leg]
```

works in `v11.3`, but indeed produces

[image]

in `v10.4`. The solution is `Evaluate`:

```
Plot[Evaluate @ fs, {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> leg]
```

[image]